# Handling ClientBase faults and SimpleIOC

Tags: mvvm-light

I am using SimpleIOC from mvvm-light along with the ViewModelLocator class / pattern provided to provide ViewModels with the correct dependencies injected.  The problem I have is that the dependency that is being injected in to my ViewModel is a WCF ClientBase instance that can "break" if it encounters a fault.  One example would be if the service it is trying to connect to doesn't exist it will cause a fault.  I don't know how to handle this properly.  Once the ClientBase derived class is in a fault state it will no longer work.  The ViewModelLocator keeps injecting this broken instance of my service proxy so even if this service becomes accessible the proxy will error out when used because it can't recover from a faulted state.  How should I deal with this?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to figure this one out on my own.  The answer was to create a wrapper around the ClientBase proxy class so that when a call created a fault, the wrapper class could properly handle the exception yet still be ready to handle the next call.